# Displaying Rich Text (.rtf) in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8, rtf

I have a `.rtf` file that I need to display within a JavaFX GUI.

My research indicates that the JavaFX [TextFlow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) supports [rich text through a tree of Node objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm).  However, I am at a loss on how to get my `.rtf` file represented as this tree of Nodes.

I feel like there should be an intuitive way to parse the `.rtf` file into the Node tree, but I just can't seem to find a way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parsing RTF and Rendering in a TextFlow**

You could parse the rtf and generate a TextFlow representation of it (similar as is done for this [markdown editor](https://github.com/eugener/markdown-pad-fx) for markdown markup).  I believe this would be a difficult task for you (the [RTF 1.9.1 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725) is 277 pages long).  Describing how to do this would be too long and complicated for a StackOverflow answer (even if I could describe it, which I probably could not).

**Converting RTF to a format JavaFX can more easily render**

I suggest using a converter (either offline or using an online service) to convert your RTF to another format before trying to render it in JavaFX.  If you know the documents in advance you can pre-convert before shipping your application, if you don't then you will have to provide a real-time conversion facility with your application.  I won't recommend a particular service, but you can google and do some research on RTF conversion to see if there is one that fits.  As a target format you could choose PDF or HTML, or an image (e.g. PNG).

JavaFX will natively display:

1. Images using an ImageView.
2. HTML using a WebView.
3. A 3rd party library can be used to display PDF documents or other formats using JavaFX.